# Change NavigationPage Backbutton color from DynamicResource

Tags: xamarin.forms, dynamicresource

Found this for change to change the color of the backbutton .

```
NavigationPage.SetIconColor(this, Color.FromHex("#FFFF00"));
```

The backgroudcolor of the page i change with `DynamicResource`.

**Invul.xaml.cs**

```
  App.Current.Resources["defaultBackgroundColor"] = Preferences.Get("BackgroundColor", "#1D252D");
```

For the Backcolor of the backbutton i tryed this but not working because **Color.FromHex** i think ,can i change the FromHex part in to ?

```
  NavigationPage.SetIconColor(this, Color.FromHex("{DynamicResource defaultBackgroundColor}"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use color from `ResourceDictionary` , you can access it first and pass the result color to the second parameter of method `NavigationPage.SetIconColor`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
        Color color = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["defaultBackgroundColor"];
        NavigationPage.SetIconColor(this, color);
```

The `defaultBackgroundColor` is a color in `Application.Resources`:

```
   <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!-- Colors -->
        <Color x:Key="defaultBackgroundColor">Red</Color>
        <Color x:Key="Yellow">#ffd966</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```